# "Every ball has quite a different colour *from each other*"

Tags: sentence-construction

Is the following sentence grammatically correct?

> Every ball has quite a different colour **from each other**.

[image]

Comment: *Color* requires an article. *Every ball... from every other ball* or *Each ... from all the other balls* but not *Every ... from each other*. *Each other* is reciprocal.

Comment: Or, you can finesse the question by saying "Each ball has a unique color."

Comment: Actually, a better sentence (consistent with the actual picture) and without changing the example sentence structure would be: "Each ball is colored differently." A reader of the original sentence would assume that each ball is mono-colored/shaded and would not mentally visualize the above image. If you only use "color", then you would have to use modifiers: color scheme, color pattern, color mix, etc. Alternately, you can make 'color" plural in this context.

Answer (score 1):

Many ways you can describe that including StoneyB's two options.

For instance,

> Every ball has a different color from every other ball 
>  Each ball has a different color from all the other balls, *or simply...* 
>  All balls are of different colors