# To have different colors or to be different colors?

Tags: word-usage, verbs

could you please tell me whether the following sentences are both grammatically correct and whether both of them sound natural?

> These objects (e.g. flowers) can have many different colors.
>
> These objects (e.g. flowers) can be many different colors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a difference between *having* a color and *being* a color.

To *be* a color is to be entirely, or predominantly, of that color (e.g. a *blue sky*). If more than one color predominates, then an object can *be* multiple colors (e.g. a *red and white striped shirt*). In contrast, to *have* a color is less exclusive; it suggests that other colors may be present, and those other colors may even be more prominent than the one you are talking about (e.g. *the flags of Taiwan, Saudia Arabia, and Slovenia all have white on them*).

To offer some real-life examples using Wikimedia Commons images, if you asked the average person what color these tulips are, the response will most likely be *yellow*, or some variety of *yellow*:

[image: Yellow tulips by Kor!An (Андрей Корзун), from https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Tulip_cv._100.JPG]

The flower below is trickier.

[image: Monsella tulip by Kor!An (Андрей Корзун), from https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Tulip_%27Monsella%27_02.JPG]

If pressed to name a single color, most people would also say this tulip *is* yellow, since the overwhelming proportion of the visible parts of the flowers (i.e. the petals) is yellow. From a distance, it will appear entirely yellow. But many will at the same time object that the flower also *has* red in it— it *is yellow with red stripes* or *is yellow, but has red stripes*.

In this third case, many may refuse from the outset to identify the flower as *being* any one color:

[image: Viola image by russavia, from https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Starburst_(2256714105).jpg]

They will say it *is purple, white, and yellow*, or that it *is white and purple and has yellow (on one petal)*. This flower *has* yellow, but it cannot be said that it *is* yellow.

In practice, to say flowers can *be* many colors and can *have* many colors is nearly equivalent. But one could draw a distinction between the two. To say flowers can *be* many colors is to say that flowers may reflect a range of predominant colors. In contrast, to say flowers can *have* many colors is to say that many colors can be found among the flowers, even if they all share the same predominant color.

Thus, if *flowers can be yellow*, you can expect flowers looking like the first or second examples. If *flowers can have yellow*, you can expect flowers looking like any of the three examples.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it also alright to say something like the following sentence? "This bunny is a darker brown." I'm not entirely sure whether the article "a" is ok here.

Answer (score 6):

Both are correct, but the second one sounds more natural to me.  Also, they have *slightly* different meanings.

When I hear "the flowers can **be** many different colors" I think of a type of flower that can be red OR blue OR any other color (but a solid color, not mixed).  A rose can be red OR white OR pink (but entirely red or entirely white, not at the same time).  If that makes sense.

When I hear "the flowers can **have** many different colors" I think of flowers that are multi-colored.  Like a flower that can have red AND blue AND green, all on one flower.

"**be**" many different colors = red OR blue OR green

"**have**" many different colors = red AND blue AND green

This is not always the case but it is the difference I think of.

Answer (score 1):

Actually all that has been said does not explain why English prefers to say

- 1 What colour are his eyes? And not: 2 What colour have his eyes?

I think that the variant 1 was originally

- Of what colour are his eyes?

In the course of time "of" was dropped as describing the colour of something is a frequent topic. So we actually have a shortened expression.

The drop of "of" is for me the only reason why English says: What colour is her hair? and not: What colour has her hair? as a lot of speakers of other languages would say.

It would be fine if I or others could find something that would back up my theory.

Added: In this question [Link](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/52459/every-ball-has-quite-a-different-colour-from-each-other) we find "Every ball has a different color" and "All balls are of different color.

Comment: +1 - There is a traditional American folk Song called _East/Old Virginia._  If you dig around in older field recordings and transcriptions, you'll find the heroine of the song described with `feature` **of a** `color`:  Buell Kazee sang _Her hair it was of a dark brown curly. Her cheeks they were of a rosy red._  Jean Ritchie sings that _Her cheeks they were of a brightsome color."_  Dan Tate sang that _her eyes were of a diamond blue._  Some of those recordings are collected here: https://oldweirdamerica.wordpress.com/2011/11/09/58-east-virginia-by-buell-kazee/

Answer (score 0):

They are both true, both are grammatically correct and they both sound natural.

It's an oddity of English that we refer to things as both *having* and *being* colours.  Which one you use is simply down to preference.